# Using Embedded POJO class in Green Dao annotated Entity

Tags: android, greendao

I want to use embedded POJO class in my persistent entity.

It is needed to match the server data model in my android app. App using GreeanDao framework for DB DAO layer and self-written annotated-based library for data exchange with server*
*I just want to mention it to say that rewriting library to match restrictions can be a solution too but before it, I want to figure out if there is a natural way or existing use case.

I believe I can use `@Transient` annotation with my POJO field and keep the copy of POJO fields in Entity class than just messing with setters of copy fields and constructor Green Daou relies on to initialize POJO field. 
But it sounds little clumsy if you ask me.

```java
public class Person{
        private String firstName, secondName;
        private int age;
        /* getters and setters */
    }
```

```java
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Entity;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Id;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Keep;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Property;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Transient;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Generated;

@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private long id;
    @Transient
    private Person person;
    @Property(nameInDb = "PERSON_FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;
    @Property(nameInDb = "PERSON_SECOND_NAME")
    private String secondName;
    @Property(nameInDb = "PERSON_AGE")
    private int age;


    @Keep
    public Employee(long id, String firstName, String secondName, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.age = age;
        initPerson();
    }

    @Generated(hash = 202356944)
    public Employee() {
    }

    private void initPerson(){
        if(this.person == null)
            this.person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName(this.firstName);
        person.setSecondName(this.secondName);
        person.setAge(this.age);
    }


    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
        this.setAge(person.getAge());
        this.setFirstName(person.getFirstName());
        this.setSecondName(person.getSecondName());
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        initPerson();
    }

    public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
        this.secondName = secondName;
        initPerson();
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        initPerson();
    }
    /* some getters etc */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out using similar method but with little modification. I keep use annotation ToOne. It is important to check the String personId instead of person.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private long id;
    private String personId;
    @ToOne(joinProperty = "personId")
    private Person person;

    @Keep
    public Employee(long id) {
        this.id = id;
        initPerson();
    }

    @Generated(hash = 202356944)
    public Employee() {
    }

    private void initPerson() {
        if (this.personId == null){
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName(this.firstName);
        person.setSecondName(this.secondName);
        person.setAge(this.age);
        setPerson(person)
        }
    }
     /** called by internal mechanisms, do not call yourself. */
@Generated(hash = 472550346)
public void setPerson(Person person) {
    synchronized (this) {
        this.person= person;
        personId = person == null ? null : person.getId();
        person__resolvedKey = personId;
    }
}
    /* some getters etc */
}
```

Comment: It is not actually 'embadded' anymore. But yes - separate table with generated id it is  can be a workaround